# New to Rich Snippets (html), how do I put them in my code?

Tags: html

I've seen the question [How to implement Rich Snippets] but my question is a little more basic (since I'm not the best at HTML).

In https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/recipes the example code is

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <span itemprop="brand">ACME</span>
  <span itemprop="name">Executive Anvil</span>
  <img itemprop="image" src="anvil_executive.jpg" alt="Executive Anvil logo" />
  <span itemprop="description">Sleeker than ACME's Classic Anvil, the
    Executive Anvil is perfect for the business traveler
    looking for something to drop from a height.
  </span>
  Product #: <span itemprop="mpn">925872</span>
  <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <span itemprop="ratingValue">4.4</span> stars, based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">89
      </span> reviews
  </span>

  <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    Regular price: $179.99
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
    $<span itemprop="price">119.99</span>
    (Sale ends <time itemprop="priceValidUntil" datetime="2020-11-05">
      5 November!</time>)
    Available from: <span itemprop="seller">Executive Objects</span>
    Condition: <link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/UsedCondition"/>Previously owned,
      in excellent condition
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock"/>In stock! Order now!</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I'm wondering, do I just copy and paste this into the HTML on my page? (with my information obviously). Will it mess up my page? Change the formatting? Will anything display on my page? Or will it just act like a comment but search crawlers from google will realize what it is and make use of it.

Also, how long after I add this code to an existing page (that google as already indexed) will the google search results be updated to show the Rich Text Snippet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your questions...

**Do I just copy and paste this into the HTML on my page?**

Yes, that's all you need to do. You don't even have to copy all the code, you can use your custom code (with different HTML elements) and just add them proper rich snippet attributes.

The first thing you need is a wrapper (mostly div, but doesn't really matter to the rich snippets themselves) with itemscope and itemtype attributes for the item you want to add rich snippets to, like product in your case:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
```

Then, inside this `<div>`, you can add the itemprop attribute to any elements. The only limitation is that you can't use any itemprop, you have to choose only those that are specified on the related schema.org page, [Product - schema.org](http://schema.org/Product) in your case.

**Will it mess up my page? Change the formatting?**

Not at all! There rich snippets are just custom HTML attributes, nothing else.

If you want to be sure that you've set everything correctly (and I do recommend doing so), use [Google Developers' Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/). Just copy there your code or link to your site with implemented Rich Snippets and see for yourself.

**Will anything display on my page? Or will it just act like a comment but search crawlers from google will realize what it is and make use of it.**

Nothing will display on your page unless you make a bad syntax error and that's not really probable as the syntax is just simple HTML. Rich snippets will act a little bit like comments in the way that they will not be rendered by the browsers, but they are not comments, they are just HTML attributes. There are plenty of HTML attributes which are not rich snippets and not rendered either.

**How long after I add this code to an existing page (that google as already indexed) will the google search results be updated to show the Rich Text Snippet?**

Depends on the traffic you site has (the more traffic, the more often Google crawlers visits your site). You can tell Google to crawl your site as soon as possible via [this Google Webmaster Tools Crawler form](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?pli=1). However, you can't be sure that this method will be effective enough. It's generally better to create your own [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) account and submit your site for crawling. It could take approximately 14 days, but I can't guarantee this.

I hope these answers will help you.

**// Update concerning a preview of the page with rich snippets in SERP**

[The Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) used to create a preview. Nevertheless, [it has been updated in the middle of January 2015](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.cz/2015/01/new-structured-data-testing-tool.html) and it doesn't show the preview anymore. It seems that it's not currently possible at all, not even in Google Webmaster Tools. Correct me if I'm wrong as the [Google help page of Rich snippets testing tool](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2595559?hl=en) says that "a preview of how that page might appear in Google search results" will be displayed in the tool, maybe the page just hasn't been updated yet.

If you wonder how the old version (that doesn't exist anymore) looked like, have a look at [this older article](http://searchengineland.com/google-upgrades-their-rich-snippets-testing-tool-to-better-reflect-display-in-search-results-133872) with screenshots. I find this older version simpler, but one can't stop the progress.

Comment: Thanks a ton! answered all the questions I have. One more quick question about the "How long after I add the code...". Is there a way to "preview" my website search results? Basically to tell that the Rich Text Snippet is working before google crawls it.